Moving or copying a Thunderbird profile to the same version fails
Recently, I needed to import a saved Mozilla Thunderbird profile from a drive image made the day before. It should have been simple -- the newly-installed email client was the same version as that in the image, v. 128.4.2 esr, the operating system was the same, Windows 10 22H2. In the past, I'd just copied the whole folder,
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird,
and all my settings and downloaded IMAP email messages would be brought over.
However, on doing that, a message was displayed that the profile was not compatible with this version of Thunderbird!
After uninstalling Thunderbird, and then reinstalling, I tried using the Tools -> Import dialog to bring in the data via Import from another Thunderbird installation. That failed, too, for unspecified reasons... nevertheless, accounts were created, but no login or passwords came though.
How can I bring back that profile without having to restore the whole drive?

After additional attempts to restore data, I finally found a second set of Thunderbird profiles in
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Thunderbird,
in addition to that in
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird.

Though I've no idea if this issue is common, or if it resulted from having Thunderbird updated multiple time from 2019 through 2024, it might help others trying to copy a profile. It reminds me of the non-PC Python issue concerning two sheds.
